# set /p crashes when i enter something with space at end

Tags: windows, batch-file, crash

```
 set /p name= Enter the NAME :

 if [%name%]==[] goto input_failed
```

when i enter some name gani_(where _ is space) then my script crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this -

```
set /p "name= Enter the NAME :"

echo.%name%

if "%name%"=="" goto input_failed
```

Sample output

```
D:\>draft.bat

D:\>set /p "name= Enter the NAME :"
Enter the NAME :gane

D:\>echo.gane
gane

D:\>if "gane " == "" goto input_failed
```

Cheers, G

Answer (score 0):

```
set "name="
set /p "name= Enter the NAME :"
```

Then any of the following will do the test

```
 if "%name%"=="" goto input_failed
 if not defined name goto input_failed
```